# Importing a large SQL file into a local Firebird database

Tags: python, firebird

I'm trying to import a large SQL file (15k+ statements) into a new local Firebird database with Python, through [*fdb*](http://pythonhosted.org/fdb/) module.

```
import fdb

db = fdb.create_database("CREATE DATABASE 'test.fdb'")
sql_str = open('test.sql').read()
in_trans = False

for stmt in sql_str.split(';'):
    if stmt.startswith('INSERT') and not in_trans:
        in_trans = True
        db.begin()
    else:
        in_trans = False
        db.commit()

    db.execute_immediate(stmt)
```

I haven't found any better way to do this... (like using a sort of `executescript()` in *sqlite3* module which executes multiple statements per call).

It worked for first few statements, than it stopped and raised that exception:

```
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while executing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -104\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -104\n- Client SQL dialect 0 does not support reference to BIGINT datatype', -104, 335544569)
```

From what I read in Firebird documentation, I've to use SQL dialect 3 to be able to use BIGINT datatype in table schemas. I'm already correctly setting database SQL dialect 3 with `fdb.create_database()` default arguments, but I'm still need to set client SQL dialect and I've no idea where and how I do that. I'm using Firebird 2.5.2 and Python 2.7.2 on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `fdb` should default to dialect 3, but you can specify it explicitly using connection property dialect=3, see example 2 in [Connecting to a database](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/python/fdb/getting-started.html#connecting-to-a-database). The weird thing is though that there is no such thing as a dialect 0 in Firebird.

If that does solve the problem, I'd suggest you file a bug in the issue tracker as the driver should default to dialect 3: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/PYFB

Comment: Yay, dialect 0 means that no dialect is being set, that's kinda weird... I've followed your suggestion and filed a bug in their tracker: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/PYFB-38

Answer (score 0):

Better way to import large sql file into firebird database is to use [isql](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/isql.html)

Answer (score 0):

isql -user sysdba -pass

not 100% sure above is exactly right syntax

isql -user sysdba -pass  test.fdb < test.sql